# Google Compute Engine (GCE) - CentOS Image broken (cannot update/upgrade)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, centos7

1. Summarize the problem

I created a GCE VM, chose CentOS.

> $cat /etc/centos-release

`CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

The first thing I usually do is issue an update:

> $sudo yum update -y

When I do this, I get errors that the update repos do not exist.

---

This has not happened with past CentOS images, the latest/newest image has errors in the installed/active repos.

How can I fix this, or get in touch with Google to pull this CentOS image, and get a working one in place, so that I and others do not have this problem.

I can't be the only one seeing this, I would think Google would test their images before making them available to the world.

---

Error Message: see below

2. Provide background including what you've already tried

I wen to the URL that the update complains it can't find, and yup, it's not there, it's the wrong URL.

3. Show some code

   > $sudo yum update -y
4. Describe expected and actual results including any error messages

I would expect the system to be updated, but I get this horrid error message, indicating the CentOS image was not put together correctly.

Expected: I want Google to pull the image, replace with a working CentOS image that does not give grief, and does not suck away my entire morning sorting through this.

**ERROR MESSAGE** (with $sudo yum update -y)

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed connect to mirrorlist.centos.org:80; Operation now in progress"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Comment: Could you check /etc/resolv.conf for valid and accessible nameserver lines? Also, paste the output of `ping mirrorlist.centos.org` and `nslookup mirrorlist.centos.org`.

Comment: I noticed that a new image of CentOS was posted on 2019-Jun-19, so I used that, deleted the 7.6.1810 VM before I saw this.

I will try to recreate with 1810 if I can find it.

With CentOS 7.6.1905, I did not have this problem.  I did not have the problem with 7.6.1810 outside of GCE.

Comment: Ok, I'll be waiting for the results.